# Explicit Register Variables in Ada

Tags: ada

C allows you to create explicit register variables which force the compiler to store the variable in a specific register (not just any General Purpose Register):

`register int *p2 asm ("r1") = t1;`

Is there an equivalent in Ada?

Comment: What is the higher purpose? Optimization? Variable inspection ?

Comment: I'm writing the last part of a bootloader which needs to clear the General Purpose Registers and then write a value into a special register (RISC-V csr) to jump to the main firmware. The value to be written will be passed from Ada into the inline Asm block. Ideally it would be placed in a specific GPR, so that I can avoid clearing that GPR in my inline assembly code. I have a workaround involving moving %0 (the register which the compiler chooses for my input value) to a known register. However, I was hoping that there would be a direct way to tell the compiler which GPR to put the input into.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with machine code insertions as described in section 13.8 of the [Ada Language Reference Manual](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-8.html).

Comment: Could you provide a specific example? As an ADA beginner, this page in the Reference Manual is difficult to understand.

Comment: Count the number of ways that page mentions "implementation-defined"! That’s why there are no details. You’ll find GNAT-related info [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugn/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/inline_assembler.html), but of course even with that the actual machine instructions/registers will differ between machine architectures (e.g. ARM vs Intel)

Comment: GNAT Reference Manual on Machine Code [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/implementation_of_specific_ada_features.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand how to write an Asm code insertion and how to pass in Ada variables as inputs, but how can I force the compiler to put these variables into a specific register? I can see that there are specific register constraints for x86 (eg "a" for eax) but such constraints do not exist for other architectures such as RISC-V. This is why I was asking about the Explicit Register Variable syntax in my original question.